# Implement the search functionality using Cloud Firestore and Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search, firebaseui

I am in the process of implementing an item search in a recyclerview. I am using Android studio and Cloud Firestore. Looking for an article I get the following error:

> Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter

How can I not execute `orderBy` on `"ville"`? I do not understand

I would like to be able to proceed in this way to achieve the result. What I'm really looking for is the list is already filtering from the entry of the first character. Thank you

My searchBox is actually an EditText.

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Query query = db.collection("RESTO_TABLE").orderBy("ville",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                    .whereGreaterThan("ville",s)
                    .whereLessThan("ville",s+"\uf8ff");
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<RestoModel> Options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<RestoModel>()
                    .setQuery(query,RestoModel.class)
                    .build();
            villeAdapter = new VilleAdapter(Options);
            villeAdapter.startListening();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(villeAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Query query = db.collection("RESTO_TABLE").orderBy("ville",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                    .whereGreaterThan("ville",s)
                    .whereLessThan("ville",s+"\uf8ff");
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<RestoModel> Options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<RestoModel>()
                    .setQuery(query,RestoModel.class)
                    .build();
            villeAdapter = new VilleAdapter(Options);
            villeAdapter.startListening();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(villeAdapter);

            }
        });
```

Trace de pile :

FirestoreRecycler: onError
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter ville
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:117)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(EventManager.java:166)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.removeAndCleanupTarget(SyncEngine.java:534)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(SyncEngine.java:418)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider$RemoteStoreCallback.handleRejectedListen(MemoryComponentProvider.java:99)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(RemoteStore.java:562)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:446)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(RemoteStore.java:53)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:176)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:108)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:38)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1(AbstractStream.java:119)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(AbstractStream.java:67)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(AbstractStream.java:110)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(FirestoreChannel.java:125)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:658)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:643)
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:229)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter ville
at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:541)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:115)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(EventManager.java:166) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.removeAndCleanupTarget(SyncEngine.java:534) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(SyncEngine.java:418) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider$RemoteStoreCallback.handleRejectedListen(MemoryComponentProvider.java:99) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(RemoteStore.java:562) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:446) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(RemoteStore.java:53) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:176) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:108) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:38) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1(AbstractStream.java:119) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(AbstractStream.java:67) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(AbstractStream.java:110) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(FirestoreChannel.java:125) 
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:658) 
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:643) 
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) 
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:229) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WatchStream]: (70907c) Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=Target id not found: 68, cause=null}.

When i used "where clause"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing the API syntax from Firebase Realtime Database, with the one from Firestore. On Firestore, you can perform this search with:

```
db.collection("RESTO_TABLE")
  .orderBy("ville")
  .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("ville", s)
  .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("ville", s + "\uf8ff")
```

**Update**: The query syntax on Swift is different. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#swift_2

Comment: Thank you Mr. Franck for your answer. In fact I had seen some choice of genre but I was not able to make a big choice because the "where" is colored in red. See the attached image thank you, if you had an idea, I am interested

Comment: If the name is colored in red, you'll typically get an error message when you hover over it (or in the compiler output).

Comment: Exactly, when i hover the "where" i got the text : cannot resolve method "where" in Query

Comment: Ah, I see now. The query syntax for Swift is slightly different. See the updated code in my answer **and** the docs that I linked.

Comment: sorry Franck
I am still looking for a way to make the request finction. The condition did not succeed. sorry for the delay

Comment: @Rolanddev did you receive a new error or what is wrong after testing Frank answer?

Comment: I can't use the "where" clause apparently it's colored red and returns the message: cannot resolve method 'where' in 'Query' / cannot resolve method 'where' (java.lang.String,?)

Comment: Ahm, I now see the cause of that: I has used Flutter syntax in my answer, while you are using Android/Java. I updated the code in my answer to use Android/Java syntax of the APIs. In general when something doesn't work, describe what is **does** do rather than just saying it didn't work, as it's much more likely we can help with additional information about the (new) problem.